# バックエンドメモ帳

Tags: monaca

MonacaクラウドのBasicプランを試しています。

サンプルアプリの バックエンド メモ帳 を試したくて、
これを元にプロジェクトを作成し、Monacaバックエンドも作成しました。
（バックエンドの名称は「MemoBK」、コレクション名は「Memo」）
IDEの「プレビュー」で実行したのですが、
LoginPageの「Login」ボタンを押しても、
RegisterPageの「Register」ボタンを押しても、
なにも反応しません。

app.jsの
MC.User.register(email, password)
とか
MC.User.login(email, password)
の直前まで実行されていることは確認できました。

これは、バックエンドの名前が悪いのでしょうか？
IDEの「プレビュー」では実行できないからでしょうか？
「Monacaデバッガー」を使う必要があるということでしょうか？
もしくは、そもそもBasicプランではダメなのでしょうか？

すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: とりあえずBasicプランでもiPhoneのMonacaデバッガーからなら動きました（Androidは持っていないので未確認）。

Comment: そういうことなのですね。
大変、助かりました。
ありがとうございます！